# Copy the content of NSTableView row or column using the default Copy menu item in Coca applicaton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have several NSTableViews in different NSViewControllers. In my main application window I have a menu which has Edit->Copy command. This command is always disabled, so when I select a row or column in any of my NSTableViews, I can't use it.

Can anyone tell me how to enable the COPY menu item?

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733209/how-to-copy-rows-from-nstableview) here but it didn't help. In all my NSTableViews,all text cells have the checkbox RefusesFirstResponder unhecked.

Also, just to mention that I have some custom menu items in the menu which works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy command will be enabled if an object in the responder chain responds to the `copy:` message. The solution is to implement the `copy:` method in a controller which is in the responder chain like the viewcontroller or the windowcontroller.

Comment: Indeed, after adding the - (void) copy:(id)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    // some code to put data on the pasteBoard
} menu copy is enabled...However, it does nothing...that is if I click on copy, noting is copied. Should I now make outlet from my nstableview and somehow copy the selected row content into the pasteboard to make the copy method to work?

Comment: Yes, you have to put the data on the pasteBoard.

Comment: In anyone need start point   <br />NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];  <br />
    NSInteger changeCount = [pasteboard clearContents];  <br />
    NSInteger row = [self.customersViewController.customersTableView selectedRow];  <br />
    NSTableColumn *columnFirstName = [self.customersViewController.customersTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"firstName"];  <br />
    NSCell *cellFirstName = [columnFirstName dataCellForRow:row];  <br />
    NSArray *objectsToCopy = @[[cellFirstName stringValue]];  <br />
    BOOL OK = [pasteboard writeObjects:objectsToCopy];  <br />

Comment: With Swift, remember to proceed your declaration with @objc – `@objc func copy(_ sender: AnyObject) {}`